# How can I adjust the size and position of the Glossary title?

Tags: fonts, glossaries

I would like to adjust the position and size of the Glossaries title (the word 'Glossaries' itself) in my LaTeX document.
I would like the word to be smaller and further up the page since there is a lot of whitespace above it at the moment.

I have checked this answer: [How to change the style of "Contents" heading?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/19478/how-to-change-the-style-of-contents-heading) where they fix the problem of centering, not of font-size/vertical position. Also here: [Adjusting the left margin of glossaries](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/375280/adjusting-the-left-margin-of-glossaries) is for left and right margins and not for the title size and vertical position. This question: [Change position of glossary title](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/60804/change-position-of-glossary-title) seems specific to a two-column setup in the glossary, which I don't have.

I have also scanned through the documentation: "The glossaries package: a guide for beginners" but there is no mention of font size/position of the heading.

I searched for modifiers in \printglossary and tried using \printglossary[title={{\Large\glossaryname}}] which appears to work for font size. Is there a way to get finer control on font size than this?

The most important issue to me is the position of the title, and the short guide above doesn't seem to mention that. I know there is a more detailed guide but that is very long and I was hoping to get some advice here first.

Here is my MWE:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

% for glossary
\usepackage[toc,nonumberlist]{glossaries}
\makeglossaries

% margin size
\usepackage[margin=20mm]{geometry}


%spacing
\usepackage{setspace}
\doublespacing

\title{
{Thesis Title}\\
{\large Institution Name}\\
}
\author{Author Name}
\date{Day Month Year}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\newpage
    \tableofcontents
\newpage

%%%% Glossary

\newglossaryentry{example}
{
    name=example,
    description={An \textit{example} is an instance of something of interest, usually used for illustrative purposes.}
}

\newpage
    \printglossary[title={{\Large\glossaryname}}]
\newpage

\section{Intro}
Hi. This is an \gls{example}

\end{document}
```

I compiled using: `makeglossaries` followed by PDFLaTeX.

If there is anything else I need to add, please let me know.
Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

Use some vertical space put the word **Glossary** where you want and also where the list begins.

`toctitle=\glossaryname` is needed to avoid messing with the TOC.

The font size can be controlled using `\fontsize{<size in pt>}{<skip>}`

Using the Computer Modern font you might get a warning `LaTeX Font Warning: Size substitutions with differences`. (Or see https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/252042/161015)

The `palatine` font, for example. a Type 1 font, allows for no-fuss scaling.

```
\printglossary[title={{\vspace*{-80pt}\fontsize{19}{22}\selectfont\glossaryname\vspace*{-40pt}}}, toctitle=\glossaryname] % <<<<<<<
```

[image: x]

```
% !TeX TS-program = pdflatex

\documentclass[11pt]{report}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} % added
\usepackage{palatino} % added <<<<<<<

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

% for glossary
\usepackage[toc,nonumberlist]{glossaries}

\makeglossaries

% margin size
\usepackage[margin=20mm]{geometry}

\usepackage{showframe} % show margins <<<<< 

%spacing
\usepackage{setspace}
\doublespacing

\title{
    {Thesis Title}\\
    {\large Institution Name}\\
}
\author{Author Name}
\date{Day Month Year}   

\begin{document}
    
    \maketitle
    
    %\newpage  %not needed
    \tableofcontents
    %\newpage
    
    %%%% Glossary   
    \newglossaryentry{example}
    {
        name=example,
        description={An \textit{example} is an instance of something of interest, usually used for illustrative purposes.}
    }

        %\newpage
        \printglossary[title={{\vspace*{-80pt}\fontsize{19}{22}\selectfont\glossaryname\vspace*{-40pt}}}, toctitle=\glossaryname] % <<<<<<<
        %\newpage %\chapter will start a new page
    
\chapter{Intro}
Hi. This is an \gls{example}
\end{document}
```

Comment: This worked for me - thank you! Also, do you know how I might change the font style/size in the glossary itself? In the above answer, the font modifiers are in the title field so I don't think they'll work on the main body of the glossary. Thanks again.

Comment: You need to create a new style. See https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/170627/161015